# Elasticsearch not using "default_search" analyzer unless explicitly stated in query

Tags: elasticsearch

From reading the Elasticsearch documents, I would expect that naming an analyzer 'default_search' would cause that analyzer to get used for all searches unless another analyzer is specified. However, if I define my index like so:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/' -d '{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "my_ngram_analyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "my_ngram_tokenizer",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ],
                    "type" : "custom"
                },
                "default_search": {
                    "tokenizer" : "keyword",
                    "filter" : [
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "my_ngram_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "nGram",
                    "min_gram": "3",
                    "max_gram": "100",
                    "token_chars": []
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "TestDocument": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "metadata_template": {
                        "match_mapping_type": "string",
                        "path_match": "*",
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "multi_field",
                            "fields": {
                                "ngram": {
                                    "type": "{dynamic_type}",
                                    "index": "analyzed",
                                    "analyzer": "my_ngram_analyzer"
                                },
                                "{name}": {
                                    "type": "{dynamic_type}",
                                    "index": "analyzed",
                                    "analyzer": "standard"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}'
```

And then add a 'TestDocument':

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/TestDocument/1' -d '{
    "name" : "TestDocument.pdf" }'
```

My queries are still running through the default analyzer. I can tell because this query gives me a hit:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/TestDocument/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
    "query": {
         "match": {
                    "name.ngram": {
                        "query": "abc.pdf"
                    }
                }
    }
}'
```

But does not if I specify the correct analyzer (using the 'keyword' tokenizer)

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/TestDocument/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
    "query": {
         "match": {
                    "name.ngram": {
                        "query": "abc.pdf",
                        "analyzer" : "default_search"
                    }
                }
    }
}'
```

What am I missing to use "default_search" for searches unless stated otherwise in my query? Am I just misinterpreting expected behavior here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your dynamic template, you are setting the search and index analyzer by using "analyzer." It will only use the default as a last resort.

```
"index_analyzer":"analyzer_name" //sets the index analyzer
"analyzer":"analyzer_name" // sets both search and index
"search_analyzer":"...." // sets the search analyzer.
```

Comment: I thought that was the analyzer for indexing, not search.

Comment: "analyzer": {search AND index analyzer}
"index_analyzer":{index only}
"search_analyzer":{search only}